# Weird DAO design cause of PermGen Errors?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have inherited a VERY weird design that a previous contacting company used to implement DAOs in Java.  I believe that it is the reason I get PermGen errors constantly, but would like to see what others think.

Each DAO has one or more private static final fields.  These are of type Table.  Table is an abstract class.  Each Table implementation is implemented in-line.  In a static block, these implementations are put into a static hash map.

Is it possible that since OBJ_MAP holds implementations of the Table class, that this could cause the ClassLoader to never be able to be garbage collected?

```
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyDAO {
    private static final Table DESCRIPTION = new TableImpl("MYDESC", Types.VARCHAR);
    private static final Table CODE = new TableImpl("MYCODE", Types.VARCHAR);

    private static final Map<Table, String> OBJ_MAP = new HashMap<Table, String>();

    static {

        OBJ_MAP.put(DESCRIPTION, "description");
        OBJ_MAP.put(CODE, "code");
     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<BusinessType> getAllBusinessTypes() {
        return DAOUtil.executeObjectSelect("Select MYDESC, MYCODE, 
              from MYTABLE", BusinessType.class,
            OBJ_MAP, new BusinessType());
    }
}
```

Comment: OBJ_MAP holds instances of Table, not its definition (namely the Class objects). It would be more helpful if you can provide more details. For example, what abnormal behavior are you observing, and what code is executed when you observe it?

Comment: "Each Table implementation is implemented in-line." Not in the example code, they aren't.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I thought that was odd syntax. Table is an abstract class, so I thought the class was in-line.  I overlooked that there were no {} at the end, and didn't see the TableImpl class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every class that had static final fields of some class type prevented the ClassLoader from being garbage-collected, we wouldn't get very far in any program, so unless you can provide more information (e.g. "the DAO is loaded from class loader A, but the Table implementations come from class loader B", however that would work), I'm going to go with "No, that can't be the cause."

Comment: Yes, after looking more at the code, I don't think this is what is causing the PermGen errors.  Currently trying to find the culprit with jhat.